# How can I extract the code from .RData file and convert them in .R format?

Tags: r, rdata

I'm running into some trouble. I have Rfile which is in .RData format. I want to dig into the r-code to see how they created the project?

Is there a way to convert .RData into .R or .rmd?

I tried the below code but it is not working.

```
newEnv <- new.env()
load('C:/h.RData', newEnv)
dump(c(lsf.str(newEnv)), file="C:/normalCodeFile.R", envir=newEnv)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question, as `.RData` files aren't meant to store code. They are used to store objects, like a dataframe. Maybe I'm misreading the question?

Comment: Hmmm... `.RData` files hold objects (lists, vectors, data.frames, etc.) not textual, scripted code. Recall `.R` is simply a text file.

Comment: Yeah, that's the concern. I don't have the script file. so may be I thought we can pull out the code from .RData file